# Spatie media library does not associate media with model

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I have been fumbling around this issue for a while and I have not made any tangible progress. I am using the spatie media library component to upload files using livewire. The file is being uploaded and save as a temporary upload to the database but by the time I am calling the following code, variable 'myUpload' is null:

OrderShow.php

```php
<?php
...
class OrderShow extends Component
{
    use LivewireAlert, WithMedia;
    public $mediaComponentNames = ['myUpload'];
    public $myUpload;
    ...
    public function mount($order)
    {
        $this->order = $order;
    }
    ...
    public function submit()
    {
        //dump($this->myUpload);//this return null
        this->order->addFromMediaLibraryRequest($this->myUpload)->toMediaCollection('myupload');
        $this->clearMedia();
        $this->alert('success', 'Your files have been uploaded successfully!', ['toast' => false, 'position' =>'center']) //this toast gets shown
    }
    ...
}
```

order-show.blade.php

```html
<div class="container-xxl">
    <form wire:submit.prevent="submit">
        <x-media-library-attachment name="myUpload" />
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

config/media-library.php

```php
<?php

return [

    /*
     * The disk on which to store added files and derived images by default. Choose
     * one or more of the disks you've configured in config/filesystems.php.
     */
    'disk_name' => env('MEDIA_DISK', 'public'),

    /*
     * The maximum file size of an item in bytes.
     * Adding a larger file will result in an exception.
     */
    'max_file_size' => 1024 * 1024 * 10, // 10MB

    /*
     * This queue will be used to generate derived and responsive images.
     * Leave empty to use the default queue.
     */
    'queue_name' => '',

    /*
     * By default all conversions will be performed on a queue.
     */
    'queue_conversions_by_default' => env('QUEUE_CONVERSIONS_BY_DEFAULT', true),

    /*
     * The fully qualified class name of the media model.
     */
    'media_model' => Spatie\MediaLibrary\MediaCollections\Models\Media::class,

    /*
     * The fully qualified class name of the model used for temporary uploads.
     *
     * This model is only used in Media Library Pro (https://medialibrary.pro)
     */
    'temporary_upload_model' => Spatie\MediaLibraryPro\Models\TemporaryUpload::class,

    /*
     * When enabled, Media Library Pro will only process temporary uploads there were uploaded
     * in the same session. You can opt to disable this for stateless usage of
     * the pro components.
     */
    'enable_temporary_uploads_session_affinity' => true,

    /*
     * When enabled, Media Library pro will generate thumbnails for uploaded file.
     */
    'generate_thumbnails_for_temporary_uploads' => true,

    /*
     * This is the class that is responsible for naming generated files.
     */
    'file_namer' => Spatie\MediaLibrary\Support\FileNamer\DefaultFileNamer::class,

    /*
     * The class that contains the strategy for determining a media file's path.
     */
    'path_generator' => Spatie\MediaLibrary\Support\PathGenerator\DefaultPathGenerator::class,

    /*
     * When urls to files get generated, this class will be called. Use the default
     * if your files are stored locally above the site root or on s3.
     */
    'url_generator' => Spatie\MediaLibrary\Support\UrlGenerator\DefaultUrlGenerator::class,

    /*
     * Moves media on updating to keep path consistent. Enable it only with a custom
     * PathGenerator that uses, for example, the media UUID.
     */
    'moves_media_on_update' => false,

    /*
     * Whether to activate versioning when urls to files get generated.
     * When activated, this attaches a ?v=xx query string to the URL.
     */
    'version_urls' => false,

    /*
     * The media library will try to optimize all converted images by removing
     * metadata and applying a little bit of compression. These are
     * the optimizers that will be used by default.
     */
    'image_optimizers' => [
        Spatie\ImageOptimizer\Optimizers\Jpegoptim::class => [
            '-m85', // set maximum quality to 85%
            '--force', // ensure that progressive generation is always done also if a little bigger
            '--strip-all', // this strips out all text information such as comments and EXIF data
            '--all-progressive', // this will make sure the resulting image is a progressive one
        ],
        Spatie\ImageOptimizer\Optimizers\Pngquant::class => [
            '--force', // required parameter for this package
        ],
        Spatie\ImageOptimizer\Optimizers\Optipng::class => [
            '-i0', // this will result in a non-interlaced, progressive scanned image
            '-o2', // this set the optimization level to two (multiple IDAT compression trials)
            '-quiet', // required parameter for this package
        ],
        Spatie\ImageOptimizer\Optimizers\Svgo::class => [
            '--disable=cleanupIDs', // disabling because it is known to cause troubles
        ],
        Spatie\ImageOptimizer\Optimizers\Gifsicle::class => [
            '-b', // required parameter for this package
            '-O3', // this produces the slowest but best results
        ],
        Spatie\ImageOptimizer\Optimizers\Cwebp::class => [
            '-m 6', // for the slowest compression method in order to get the best compression.
            '-pass 10', // for maximizing the amount of analysis pass.
            '-mt', // multithreading for some speed improvements.
            '-q 90', //quality factor that brings the least noticeable changes.
        ],
    ],

    /*
     * These generators will be used to create an image of media files.
     */
    'image_generators' => [
        Spatie\MediaLibrary\Conversions\ImageGenerators\Image::class,
        Spatie\MediaLibrary\Conversions\ImageGenerators\Webp::class,
        Spatie\MediaLibrary\Conversions\ImageGenerators\Pdf::class,
        Spatie\MediaLibrary\Conversions\ImageGenerators\Svg::class,
        Spatie\MediaLibrary\Conversions\ImageGenerators\Video::class,
    ],

    /*
     * The path where to store temporary files while performing image conversions.
     * If set to null, storage_path('media-library/temp') will be used.
     */
    'temporary_directory_path' => null,

    /*
     * The engine that should perform the image conversions.
     * Should be either `gd` or `imagick`.
     */
    'image_driver' => env('IMAGE_DRIVER', 'gd'),

    /*
     * FFMPEG & FFProbe binaries paths, only used if you try to generate video
     * thumbnails and have installed the php-ffmpeg/php-ffmpeg composer
     * dependency.
     */
    'ffmpeg_path' => env('FFMPEG_PATH', '/usr/bin/ffmpeg'),
    'ffprobe_path' => env('FFPROBE_PATH', '/usr/bin/ffprobe'),

    /*
     * Here you can override the class names of the jobs used by this package. Make sure
     * your custom jobs extend the ones provided by the package.
     */
    'jobs' => [
        'perform_conversions' => Spatie\MediaLibrary\Conversions\Jobs\PerformConversionsJob::class,
        'generate_responsive_images' => Spatie\MediaLibrary\ResponsiveImages\Jobs\GenerateResponsiveImagesJob::class,
    ],

    /*
     * When using the addMediaFromUrl method you may want to replace the default downloader.
     * This is particularly useful when the url of the image is behind a firewall and
     * need to add additional flags, possibly using curl.
     */
    'media_downloader' => Spatie\MediaLibrary\Downloaders\DefaultDownloader::class,

    'remote' => [
        /*
         * Any extra headers that should be included when uploading media to
         * a remote disk. Even though supported headers may vary between
         * different drivers, a sensible default has been provided.
         *
         * Supported by S3: CacheControl, Expires, StorageClass,
         * ServerSideEncryption, Metadata, ACL, ContentEncoding
         */
        'extra_headers' => [
            'CacheControl' => 'max-age=604800',
        ],
    ],

    'responsive_images' => [
        /*
         * This class is responsible for calculating the target widths of the responsive
         * images. By default we optimize for filesize and create variations that each are 20%
         * smaller than the previous one. More info in the documentation.
         *
         * https://docs.spatie.be/laravel-medialibrary/v9/advanced-usage/generating-responsive-images
         */
        'width_calculator' => Spatie\MediaLibrary\ResponsiveImages\WidthCalculator\FileSizeOptimizedWidthCalculator::class,

        /*
         * By default rendering media to a responsive image will add some javascript and a tiny placeholder.
         * This ensures that the browser can already determine the correct layout.
         */
        'use_tiny_placeholders' => true,

        /*
         * This class will generate the tiny placeholder used for progressive image loading. By default
         * the media library will use a tiny blurred jpg image.
         */
        'tiny_placeholder_generator' => Spatie\MediaLibrary\ResponsiveImages\TinyPlaceholderGenerator\Blurred::class,
    ],

    /*
     * When enabling this option, a route will be registered that will enable
     * the Media Library Pro Vue and React components to move uploaded files
     * in a S3 bucket to their right place.
     */
    'enable_vapor_uploads' => env('ENABLE_MEDIA_LIBRARY_VAPOR_UPLOADS', false),

    /*
     * When converting Media instances to response the media library will add
     * a `loading` attribute to the `img` tag. Here you can set the default
     * value of that attribute.
     *
     * Possible values: 'lazy', 'eager', 'auto' or null if you don't want to set any loading instruction.
     *
     * More info: https://css-tricks.com/native-lazy-loading/
     */
    'default_loading_attribute_value' => null,

    /*
     * You can specify a prefix for that is used for storing all media.
     * If you set this to `/my-subdir`, all your media will be stored in a `/my-subdir` directory.
     */
    'prefix' => env('MEDIA_PREFIX', ''),
];
```

.env

```
...
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
...
```

what could be the issue?

NB: After I select a file the component makes a server round trip and saves the file to the database as TemporaryUpload model type.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you need to register the media collection.
This link above shows you how to do it.

https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-medialibrary/v10/working-with-media-collections/defining-media-collections#a-idcontent-registering-media-conversions-1-hrefcontent-registering-media-conversions-1-classanchor-link-aria-hiddentrue-titlepermalinkaa-idcontent-registering-media-conversions-hrefcontent-registering-media-conversions-classanchor-link-aria-hiddentrue-titlepermalinkaregistering-media-conversions

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).